# stylesheet_link_tag assets directory in Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started to develop in Ruby On Rails and I can not solve this problem: when I use the helper stylesheet_link_tag in the file / app / view / layouts / application.html.erb I can only reach the css file in / app / assets / stylesheets, but if I wanted to include some css files that are not found in that directory but in / app / assets / example, for example, how could I do (always using the helper stylesheet_link_tag)?

I tried to look at other pages of the forum on this topic but they were not helpful, I hope that by being more specific someone can help me ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem: in the path to the file should be placed only the filename and not the entire route, rails will then search the css files in all subfolders of `/assets`. For example if I need a css file in `/assets/css_dir/layout.css` I should only write this code:

```
<%=  stylesheet_link_tag "layout" %>
```

and nothing more. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "example/file" %>` should work for stylesheets located in `/app/assets/example`. See [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: I had already tried: it doesn't work. If I use the following line: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "example/app", media: "all" %> Rails generates this error "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/example/app.css")"

Comment: That error should only be triggered if the file is empty or non-existent.

Comment: I know, but the file is non empty and if I move it to the stylesheets subdirectory under assets it works correctly, no exception is triggered. It's a very strange situation.

Comment: @samuele - I fight this regularly, because the asset pipeline gets worse with each rails release.  Be sure the file is getting loaded via config/initializers/assets.rb - either by wildcard or individually.   With that, you may be able to dispense with the stylesheet_link_tag.  But if you do not want that sheet loaded everywhere, then it is an uphill struggle.